# Rails 3 routing looking for wrong controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

First I had this route in config/route.rb

```
get 'inbox/index' => 'inbox#index'
```

Then I ran `rake routes`, the route was correctly generated:

```
inbox_index GET  /inbox/index(.:format) {:action=>"index", :controller=>"inbox"}
```

Problem is when I tried to get the page from the browser (http://localhost:3000/inbox/index), there's an error message:

```
ArgumentError in InboxesController#index
wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
```

There is nothing in the application trace, and the right controller is generated in the env dump:

```
action_controller.instance: #<InboxController:0x7fbde79fb5a8 ...
```

Why rails tried to call `InboxesController`?

By the way, I have another route in the same application which works perfectly:

```
match "search" => 'search#search', :as => 'search', :via => [:get, :post]
```

I don't know how to isolate this problem, please give me a hint.

Comment: InboxesController#index is indeed where that route is attempting to go.   => 'inbox#index'  means the controller for the inbox resource, so it should pluralize and add controller to it, hence InboxesController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found out what happened.

I defined a method `InboxController#send`, and the metaprogramming introduced by Rails had been broken.

The error message is totally irrelevant to the situation.